What is the effect of the “IGNORECASE” flag on how the “gensub” function works with multi-byte characters?
I have the 6-byte text file (input.txt). It contains one line of three characters:
αβγ

The file is in UTF-8. It can be generated by the following command:
echo 'CEB1CEB2CEB3' | xxd -r -p > input.txt

I used the following command:
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 gawk -F '\\|' 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 0}; 
{ t = gensub(/\262{1,}/, "", "g", $0); 
print(t) > "output1.txt" }' input.txt

The output is (in hexadecimal):
CEB1CECEB30A

This is invalid UTF-8: the second character is corrupted because the B2 byte was deleted.
Then I used the following command:
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 gawk -F '\\|' 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1}; 
{ t = gensub(/\262{1,}/, "", "g", $0); 
print(t) > "output2.txt" }' input.txt

The output is (in hexadecimal):
CEB1CEB2CEB30A

This is valid UTF-8: the text can be read with no errors.
What is the explanation of the fact that these two commands generate two different outputs? What is the effect of IGNORECASE in this situation? Why is the B2 byte not deleted when the IGNORECASE flag is active?

@EdMorton: all necessary information is in the post. 1. Generate the file with the given command; 2. Use two given commands to generate two output files; 3. Compare two output files; 4. If two output files are different, then the question is: why? I did not expect a particular output. All I want is to know the reason why the B2 byte is not deleted when the IGNORECASE flag is set to 1, yet this byte is deleted when the IGNORECASE flag is set to 0. When I wrote “the second character is corrupted”, I did not mean that that was unexpected.

Assumptions/understandings:

OP's only question concerns the different output when switching between IGNORECASE=0 and IGNORECASE=1

For discussion and testing purposes I'll use the following file:
$ cat input.txt
αβγ              # lowercase
ΑΒΓ              # uppercase

NOTE: file does not contain comments
Viewing individual bytes:
$ cat input.txt | od -c
0000000 316 261 316 262 316 263  \n 316 221 316 222 316 223  \n
        ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^
           α       β       γ           Α       Β       Γ

NOTE: OP's question switches back-n-forth between octal and hexidecimal; I'm going to stick with octal with the understanding similar results will be obtained when using hexidecimal
References:
case sensitivity

Case is significant by default because IGNORECASE (like most
variables) is initialized to zero
... snip ...
In multibyte locales, the equivalences between upper- and lowercase
characters are tested based on the wide-character values of the
locale’s character set.

This is telling us a) default behavior is IGNORECASE=0 and b) case insensitive testing of characters requires taking into consideration all bytes that make up the character.
builtin variables

IGNORECASE #
If IGNORECASE is nonzero or non-null, then all string comparisons and
all regular expression matching are case-independent. This applies to
regexp matching with ... gensub() ...

When combined with the previous quote this is telling us that when IGNORECASE=1 all regex comparisons (eg, 1st arg to gensub()) are performed at the (multibyte) character level.

In OP's 1st example we see the default case-sensitive behavior of regex matching on a single byte and the removal of said byte:
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8        # run once; applies to all follow-on commands

$ gawk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=0} {print gensub(/\262/,"","g")}' input.txt | od -c

0000000 316 261 316 316 263  \n 316 221 316 222 316 223  \n
        ^^^^^^^ ^^^ ^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^
           α     ?     γ           Α       Β       Γ

In OP's 2nd example the inclusion of IGNORECASE=1 causes gawk to require all regex comparisons (eg, 1st arg to gensub()) to be processed as characters.  Since \262 is not a valid character in the utf-8 character set gensub() finds no match so nothing is changed:
$ gawk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} {print gensub(/\262/,"","g")}' input.txt | od -c

0000000 316 261 316 262 316 263  \n 316 221 316 222 316 223  \n
        ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^
           α       β       γ           Α       Β       Γ

In order to generate the same output (as IGNORECASE=0) we can override IGNORECASE=1 with the -b/--characters-as-bytes flag thus (re)enabling regex processing at the byte level:
$ gawk -b 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} {print gensub(/\262/,"","g")}' input.txt | od -c

0000000 316 261 316 316 263  \n 316 221 316 222 316 223  \n
        ^^^^^^^ ^^^ ^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^
           α     ?     γ           Α       Β       Γ

Another (correct?) approach would be to regex match on the complete multibyte character (\316\262) and replace said match with the 'leftover' byte (\316):
$ gawk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} {print gensub(/\316\262/,"\316","g")}' input.txt | od -c

0000000 316 261 316 316 263  \n 316 221 316 316 223  \n
        ^^^^^^^ ^^^ ^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^ ^^^ ^^^^^^^
           α     ?     γ           Α     ?     Γ

Notice in this case that the regex character \316\262 matches on both the lowercase (\316\262) and uppercase (\316\222) characters; both characters are replaced with the standalone byte \316!
Net results:

IGNORECASE=0 allows regex processing at the byte level
IGNORECASE=1 forces regex processing at the (multibyte) character level
-b overrides/negatesIGNORECASE=1 and returns us to regex processing at the byte level
OP's different ouputs: IGNORECASE=0 + gensub(/regex/) == regex processing at the byte level vs IGNORECASE=1 + gensub(/regex/) == regex processing at the character level


That is just an insanely good answer.

The behaviour is different when IGNORECASE is set and a multibyte character set is in use:
        /*
         * Lo these many years ago, had I known what a P.I.T.A. IGNORECASE
         * was going to turn out to be, I wouldn't have bothered with it.
         *
         * In the case where we have a multibyte character set, we have no
         * choice but to use RE_ICASE, since the casetable is for single-byte
         * character sets only.
         *
         * On the other hand, if we do have a single-byte character set,
         * using the casetable should give  a performance improvement, since
         * it's computed only once, not each time a regex is compiled.  We
         * also think it's probably better for portability.  See the
         * discussion by the definition of casetable[] in eval.c.
         */

        ignorecase = !! ignorecase;     /* force to 1 or 0 */
        if (ignorecase) {
                if (gawk_mb_cur_max > 1) {
                        syn |= RE_ICASE;
                        rp->pat.translate = NULL;
                } else {
                        syn &= ~RE_ICASE;
                        rp->pat.translate = (RE_TRANSLATE_TYPE) casetable;
                }
        } else {
                rp->pat.translate = NULL;
                syn &= ~RE_ICASE;
        }

https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/re.c#n268
And then things like:
          if ((bufp->syntax & RE_ICASE) && dfa->mb_cur_max > 1)
            {
              unsigned char buf[MB_LEN_MAX];
              unsigned char *p;
              wchar_t wc;
              mbstate_t state;

              p = buf;
              *p++ = dfa->nodes[node].opr.c;
              while (++node < dfa->nodes_len
                     && dfa->nodes[node].type == CHARACTER
                     && dfa->nodes[node].mb_partial)
                *p++ = dfa->nodes[node].opr.c;
              memset (&state, '\0', sizeof (state));
              if (__mbrtowc (&wc, (const char *) buf, p - buf,
                             &state) == p - buf
                  && (__wcrtomb ((char *) buf, __towlower (wc), &state)
                      != (size_t) -1))
                re_set_fastmap (fastmap, false, buf[0]);
            }

https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/support/regcomp.c#n295
which seems to assume the input contains valid multibyte characters and so leads me to guess that when IGNORECASE is set, the regex gets compiled to something that can never match.

“why do you expect valid output?” — I did not expect the valid UTF-8 text in the output. I expected that whether the byte is deleted does not depend on the IGNORECASE flag.

@EdMorton: I did not write anything about the invalid input. I only wrote that the first output file contains the invalid UTF-8 text.
